# linkedin apply button in wp php returns an error in console

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, linkedin-api

I tried the code from:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-with-linkedin/apply-with-linkedin-reference-docs - the One Page Flow example.
I put the code in the page where i want to show the button,
but i get an error in console:Error trying to initialize the widget! Error is :origin: error.origin.not.in.api.domains

the code looks like that(my form is in cf7):

```
<div class="wrap-form">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode( get_field('form_shortcode',42)) ?>
                    <div name="widget-holder">
                        <script type="text/javascript" 
                            src="https://www.linkedin.com/mjobs/awli/awliWidget">
                        </script>
                        apply
                        <script type="IN/AwliWidget" 
                            data-company-job-code="{15}" 
                            data-integration-context="urn:li:organization:i put here my id"
                            data-mode="BUTTON_DATA" 
                            data-callback-method="onProfileData" 
                            data-api-key=i put here my id
                            data-allow-sign-in="true">
                        </script>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        function onProfileData(profileData) {
                            var firstnameField = document.getElementsByName('your-fullname"');
                            var emailField = document.getElementsByName('your-email');
                            firstnameField.value = profileData.firstName;
                            emailField.value = profileData.emailAddress;
                        }
                        // prefill form with profile data
                    </script>
                </div>
```

Comment: _“error.origin.not.in.api.domains”_ - sounds like you failed to complete the first step of the instructions, configure a list of valid domains for your application.

Comment: so what to do? how to configure a list of valid domains?

Comment: The instructions are right there in that documentation you yourself linked to.

Comment: I dont manage to add a child application with the a post request  i try the documantation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-with-linkedin/provisioning-api

Comment: So you got to make a request to set `validJsSdkDomains` then, what exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: Where do I make the request? I'm a partner.